# Вопрос по работе рекурсивной функции

Tags: javascript, функции, dom, объекты, рекурсия

Напишите функцию, которая создаёт вложенный список UL/LI (дерево) из объекта. Как я понимаю функция createTreeText(obj) обрабатывает вложенные друг в друга  объекты.Непонятно логика работы в  блоке if. И возврат пустой строки будет в том случае если  узел

будет пустым ?

```js
    var data = {
      "Рыбы": {
        "Форель": {},
        "Щука": {}
      },
      "Деревья": {
        "Хвойные": {
          "Лиственница": {},
          "Ель": {}
        },
        "Цветковые": {
          "Берёза": {},
          "Тополь": {}
        }
      }
    };

    function createTree(container, obj) {
      container.innerHTML = createTreeText(obj);
    }

    function createTreeText(obj) { // отдельная рекурсивная функция
      var li = '';
      for (var key in obj) {
        li += '<li>' + key + createTreeText(obj[key]) + '</li>';
      }
      if (li) { //(1)
        var ul = '<ul>' + li + '</ul>'
      }
      return ul || '';
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    createTree(container, data);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: да, именно так. разве что можно было сразу сделать `return`  вместо объявления переменной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В блоке if создается разметка тега , но если узел пустой {}, то соответственно переменная li будет равна пустой строке. Если это так то тогда не создастся переменная ul.

Далее есть еще одно условие, но не очевидное (ul || ''). Если переменная ul не определена, а определяется она в блоке if, то вернуть пустую строку.
Так что да, если узел пустой, то вернется пустая строка.